# Is it safe to store json data of model class in jsp? How to retrieve the value of hidden element of jsp in jquery if it contains json data?

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp

I have two questions:

a) Is it safe to store `JSON` `data` of `model class` in the `JSP`? I am doing like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="modeljsondata" value="${modeljson}"/>
```

where `modeljson` is the `json data` representation of a `model class`.

b) If it is okay to use, how can I retrieve the value in `jquery`? This does not seem to work:

```
var retrievedValue = $("#modeljsondata"}.val();
```

The `json data` does not seem to store in the above `variable`.
I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Define *"is it safe"* We have no idea what you are exposing to user. As for approach, why can't you pass it directly to a javascript variable?